# Access of undefined property " "

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make a skip button in Adobe Flash with Action Script 3.0, but when I go to test it I get the error:

> gameMenu, Layer 'Actions', Frame 107, Line 4, Column 1 1120: Access of undefined property gamePlay.

I am not sure how to fix this, any help would be appreciated.

```
skip_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,skipF);

function skipF(e:Event):void{
    gotAndStop(105);
}
```

Comment: For starters, `gotAndStop` should be `gotoAndStop`.  Also, can we see the part of your script that has `gamePlay` in it?

Answer (score 0):

Can't find any errors. There are others like the ones in the comments other users have posted. If you're using Adobe Flash CC or CS4-6 permit debugging or launch your movies in debug mode using cntrl+shift+enter. You'll get the exact line of the error as well as any active variables that might be related to the issue.

```
skip_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, skipF);

function skipF(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(105);
}
```

Comment: Since MouseEvent is also an Event this is actually not an error. It can be helpful to use "Event" so that other events can also call the skipF function.

Comment: whoops! Flash CS3 didn't let you do that! :|